# Why Isn't ImageView being instantiated?

Tags: android, xml, nullpointerexception, imageview, android-viewpager

I'm a noob to android development and I am having trouble instantiating an ImageView within a ViewPager.  My ViewPager has 7 pages and all of them have ImageViews.  However, only the ImageView on the first page instantiates and doesn't return null when called.  I checked repeatedly to be certain that each viewpager page is referencing the correct xml and am certain that each corresponding xml has the appropriate ImageView.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

MY CODE

Working viewpager page.

```
case 0:
                resId = (R.layout.reference_layout);                
                view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);

                herb_ListView = (IndexableListView)view.findViewById(R.id.herbList);                        
                herbsListresource = res.getStringArray(R.array.herblist);

                herbsItems = new ArrayList<String>();
                Collections.addAll(herbsItems, herbsListresource);                  
                Collections.sort(herbsItems);

                ArrayAdapter<String> herbs_adapter = new CustomListAdapter(ReferenceActivity.this, R.layout.list_item_herbs);
                for (int i=0; i<herbsItems.size();i++)
                    herbs_adapter.add(herbsItems.get(i));
                herb_ListView.setAdapter(herbs_adapter);
                herb_ListView.setFastScrollEnabled(true);
                herb_ListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view, int position, long id) {

                        View toolbar = view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);                                            

                        String herb_info = herb_ListView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString() + "_info";
                        String new_herb_info = herb_info.replaceAll("\\s+", "").replace("'", "").replace(".", "");
                        Log.e("herb_info result", new_herb_info);
                        String herb_pic = herb_ListView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString().toLowerCase() + "_picture";
                        String new_herb_pic = herb_pic.replaceAll("\\s+", "").replace("'", "").replace(".", "");                                                
                        Log.e("herb_pic result", new_herb_pic);

                        try{
                            ((ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.herb_image)).setImageResource((ReferenceActivity.this.getResources().getIdentifier(new_herb_pic, "drawable", ReferenceActivity.this.getApplicationInfo().packageName)));
                            ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.herb_description)).setText((ReferenceActivity.this.getResources().getIdentifier(new_herb_info, "string", ReferenceActivity.this.getApplicationInfo().packageName)));
                        }catch(Exception e){
                            Log.e("Herb Info Error", "Error loading Herb Info >> " + e.getMessage() + " //" + e.toString());
                        }

                        //Setting Arrows
                        if(((ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.chevron)).getTag()=="down"||((ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.chevron)).getTag()==null){                             
                            ((ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.chevron)).setImageResource(R.drawable.chevron_white);
                            ((ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.chevron)).setTag("up");
                        }else{
                            ((ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.chevron)).setImageResource(R.drawable.chevron_white_down);
                            ((ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.chevron)).setTag("down");
                        }

                        // Creating the expand animation for the item
                        ExpandAnimation expandAni = new ExpandAnimation(toolbar, 500);

                        // Start the animation on the toolbar
                        toolbar.startAnimation(expandAni);
                    }
                });


                ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, 0);
                return view;
```

Non-working viewpager page.

```
case 4:
                resId = (R.layout.reference_layout);    
                view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);

                crystals_ListView = (IndexableListView)view.findViewById(R.id.herbList);                        
                crystalsListresource = res.getStringArray(R.array.crystallist);

                crystalsItems = new ArrayList<String>();
                Collections.addAll(crystalsItems, crystalsListresource);                
                Collections.sort(crystalsItems);

                ArrayAdapter<String> crystals_adapter = new CustomListAdapter(ReferenceActivity.this, R.layout.list_item_crystals);
                for (int i=0; i<crystalsItems.size();i++)
                    crystals_adapter.add(crystalsItems.get(i));
                crystals_ListView.setAdapter(crystals_adapter);
                crystals_ListView.setFastScrollEnabled(true);
                crystals_ListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view, int position, long id) {

                        View toolbar = view.findViewById(R.id.crystal_toolbar);                                            

                        String crystal_sign = crystals_ListView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString() + "_definition";
                        String new_crystal_sign =  crystal_sign.replaceAll("\\s+", "").replace("'", "").replace(".", "").replace("(", "").replace(")", "");
                        Log.e("crystal_sign result", new_crystal_sign);

                        String crystal_mode = crystals_ListView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString() + "_optimumday";
                        String new_crystal_mode =  crystal_mode.replaceAll("\\s+", "").replace("'", "").replace(".", "").replace("(", "").replace(")", "");
                        Log.e("crystal_mode_result", crystal_mode);

                        String crystal_usage = crystals_ListView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString() + "_usage";
                        String new_crystal_usage =  crystal_usage.replaceAll("\\s+", "").replace("'", "").replace(".", "").replace("(", "").replace(")", "");
                        Log.e("crystal_usage_result", new_crystal_usage);

                        try{
                            TextView crystalSign = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.crystal_sign);
                            TextView crystalMode = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.crystal_mode);
                            TextView crystalUsage = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.crystal_usage);
                            crystalSign.setText("Sign: " +(ReferenceActivity.this.getResources().getIdentifier(new_crystal_sign, "string", ReferenceActivity.this.getApplicationInfo().packageName)));
                            crystalMode.setText("Mode: " +(ReferenceActivity.this.getResources().getIdentifier(new_crystal_mode, "string", ReferenceActivity.this.getApplicationInfo().packageName)));
                            crystalUsage.setText("Usage: " +(ReferenceActivity.this.getResources().getIdentifier(new_crystal_usage, "string", ReferenceActivity.this.getApplicationInfo().packageName)));

                        }catch(Exception e){
                            Log.e("Crystal Info Error", "Error loading Crystal Info >> " + e.getMessage() + " //" + e.toString());
                        }

                        //Setting Arrows
                        ImageView chevron = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.crystal_chevron);
                        if(chevron.getTag()=="down"||chevron.getTag()==null){   //NULLPOINTER THROWN HERE.                          
                            chevron.setImageResource(R.drawable.chevron_white);
                            chevron.setTag("up");
                        }else{
                            chevron.setImageResource(R.drawable.chevron_white_down);
                            chevron.setTag("down");
                        }


                        // Creating the expand animation for the item
                        ExpandAnimation expandAni = new ExpandAnimation(toolbar, 500);

                        // Start the animation on the toolbar
                        toolbar.startAnimation(expandAni);
                    }
                });

                ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, 0);
                return view;
```

Non-working viewpager xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/crystal_title"
    android:layout_width="275dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:padding="20dip"
    android:textSize="20dp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/crystal_chevron"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:src="@drawable/chevron_white_down" 
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:padding="20dip"/>

</LinearLayout>

<!-- *********************** -->
<!-- *** TOOLBAR LAYOUT **** -->
<!-- *********************** -->

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/crystal_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dip"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-50dip"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="gone" >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/crystal_sign"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:padding="2dip"
        android:text="No information available" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/crystal_mode"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:padding="2dip"
        android:text="No information available" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/crystal_usage"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:padding="2dip"
        android:text="No information available" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any hard proof for this but my thoughts on why only views within the first fragment in the `ViewPager` can be found is because the others do not "exist." Sure, they exist in XML, but I don't know that all layouts are inflated and matinatined once the `Fragments` are added such that you can update them directly if the UI is not visible (or at all).

I also do not think you can use `findViewById` to reach a view within a `Fragment` hosted by your `ViewPager`. `findViewById` only looks within the content view supplied - i.e. the layout for that activity - or a specific layout you supply to it - e.g. if you inflate a particular layout, like that of a list item, and then call `findViewById` on that to find a view inside, like a `TextView`. You should not be able to just call `findViewById` on a view for some `Fragment` and change it.

As to fixing the problem. Your views should be initialized within the fragments themselves. If you're tring to update the view in the fragment based on something that occurs in your `FragmentActivity` then I would try this

(1) Keep a reference to the fragments you are adding to your `ViewPager`

```
Private whateverFragment f1 

//initialize onCreate
f1= new WhateverFragment();
```

(2) Declare a public method in that fragment you can use to update the view you want. Note the view is initialized within the fragment not the host activity.

```
public updateTextView(String idk){
    TextView message = (TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.message);
    message.setText(idk); 
}
```

(3) if you want to know the update is complete, or commuicate back from the fragment to the fragment activity, just use an `interface`. The easiest way to do it is to declare an interface in your fragment, implement that interface in the host activity, and initialize the interface within the fragments onAttach method. This way you can callback between the fragment and its host activity.

Using this approach you can pretty much control everything within your fragment from the activity containing the view pager